# No application found for TargetPlatform.android_x86

Tags: android, flutter, dart, android-manifest, manifest

This's my first flutter App and for some reason the Android launcher icon stopped showing so I was trying to fix that, I did a bunch of things and ended up with this error.

- flutter doctor shows everything is fine.
- ios version builds just fine.

p.s I ran `flutter create`. with no luck.

The IDE log

```
No application found for TargetPlatform.android_x86.
Is your project missing an android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml?

Consider running "flutter create ." to create one.
```

Comment: If you have an <activity-alias> in your AndroidManifest.xml it's probably this issue: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/80532

Answer (score 78):

I solved this by `flutter clean`.

Answer (score 66):

Add package back in the manifest file.

Android Studio 'Chipmunk' *(2021.2.1)* had recommended that I remove `package` in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example">
```

And it added namespace in `android/app/build.gradle`:

```
namespace 'com.example'
```

This didn't immediately break my app, but after cleaning everything, it broke it, and the only fix was to revert, so that the package name remained in the `AndroidManifest.xml`, as it was before.

The error I was getting was:

```
package identifier or launch activity not found.
Please check /example/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml for errors.
No application found for TargetPlatform.android_arm64.
Is your project missing an android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml?
Consider running "flutter create ." to create one.
```

Comment: Fixed by adding package back in manifest file

Comment: Me too, fixed by adding package back in manifest file.

Comment: Adding back the attribute package="our app subdomain name" into the first line solved the issue for me. There is no clean for flutter clean/create/pub get/anything.

Answer (score 22):

**--- Error I got ---**

```
package identifier or launch activity not found.
Please check /example/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml for errors.
No application found for TargetPlatform.android_arm64.
Is your project missing an android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml?
Consider running "flutter create ." to create one.
```

**Step 1:**  Go to AndroidManifest.xml

Add ***package="com.example"*** , repalce with your own package name.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example">
```

**Step 2:**

```
flutter clean
```

**Step 3:**

```
flutter pub get
```

Hope it will solve your issue.

Answer (score 12):

Add or Update

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.example.name">
```

**package="com.example.name"**

Answer (score 8):

If `flutter clean` doesnt work manually delete `build` folder in project root directory.

Answer (score 5):

**The Best Solution ever**

1. open AndroidManifest.xml
2. add package="com. example"

> ```
> <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" `package="com.example">`
> ```

3. change example with your Package name
4. flutter clean
5. flutter pub get

Comment: Adding package to the manifest is deprecated in gradle 8.  Use the android/namespace parameter in build.gradle instead.

Answer (score 3):

For me, on removing the intent filter

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
</intent-filter>
```

I got this error, on putting it back the error resolved itself.

Answer (score 3):

in the terminal window run "flutter clean" and then "flutter pub get"
It will fix it

Answer (score 3):

**What worked for me?**

1. Did a Flutter build to generate Android APK  -> **It was successfully built**
2. Then tried outrunning the Android app on the Android emulator and the device, it worked as usual.

**What didn't work for me?**

3. Restarting the Android Studio
4. Issuing `flutter clean`, `flutter pub get`, `flutter packages get`
5. Restarting the computer
6. Re-cloning the code repository and trying to run the app with a different source code instance
7. Re-importing the Flutter project to Android studio
8. Setting up environment variables

**So the conclusion:**

Most probably due to some busy times I could have closed or stopped an Android build that was ongoing and it has caused a corrupted state in some of the files in the pub cache and which had caused this issue. Got resolved this issue along with some help from my office colleague as well.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is "fixed" when some build data is already there, for example when running `flutter build apk --debug` and then `flutter run`.

Answer (score 3):

My manifest was missing package tag:

make sure first two lines are containing `package="com.example"`
first two lines should be in this sequence:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example">
```

Comment: package is deprecated in Gradle 8

Answer (score 2):

I created a new project, made sure the new project runs successfully. Then I copied the android folder to the broken project.

Answer (score 2):

I had these same issues, none of the above solutions worked for me. I instead solved it by

1. Updating my dart SDK check out the instructions [here as specified in the dart document](https://dart.dev/get-dart)
2. Ran `flutter doctor` afterwards and it seemed flutter couldn't find the location for my android SDK, (I don't know how) I, therefore, added it with `flutter config --android-sdk /Users/<name>/Library/Android/sdk` (since i am using a mac).
3. `flutter doctor` once more to confirm everything looks ok.
4. Next I ran `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get`.
5. `flutter run` and everything looks good.

Comment: It works for me.

Answer (score 1):

I created a new flutter project and replaced the lib folder, pubspec.yaml and copied the assets folder(if any).It works!

Answer (score 1):

So I was editing intent-filter inside manifest.xml and removed few on rewriting below inside intent-filter everything got working

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved by:

1. Opening the terminal and running this code: `flutter clean`
2. `flutter pub get`
3. If this doesn't work, use **Ctrl+F5** and Wait for the process that run automatically

Answer (score 1):

An extreme answer for those still facing this problem, delete the `android` folder and then only run the `flutter create .` command. Beware if you have any changes made in the `android` folder though.

Answer (score 1):

In my solution after upgrade gradle in AndroidManifest.xml missing

**package="com.example. my name here"**

Answer (score 1):

I got this error while running my flutter application, tried all the above and none of them worked. So I `manually removed the build folder` and tried building again, and it worked like a charm. Must be due to file corruption.

Answer (score 0):

My short term solution is to reinstall the android studio , there is a closed issue on github https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/19869 tackling the exact problem but closed due to insufficient info, consider reopening it.

Comment: I've created a new test project and it built successfully, I also opened my current project in vsCode and ran in from there.. same error.

Comment: i test all the above and nothing useful for me

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem

I tried using the terminal of Android Studio but I could not resolve it.
However, when I used

```
flutter create .
```

in the terminal of the machine, it worked perfectly solving my problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. go to your project folder .
2. type **flutter clean**
3. then run your project
   (it is temporary crush problem)
   (it occur when your system suddenly shutdown like that)

Answer (score 0):

I have solve this problem by Adding        in app/main/AndroidMainifest.xml

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Comment: It would be preferable for you to edit your answer to add info rather than adding a comment

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `flutter clean` ,

I used `flutter clean`
It doesnt work  and casuing so many errors .

then I used `flutter create .`
it is recreating  my project and works   smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

android build tools was not installed while after installing, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

This error is due some miss configuration in the AndroidManifest.xml.

In my case The meta-data tag for flutterEmbedding was inside the activity tag, and this was causing the error

If you have another running project, just compare the two files and you should probably find what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved by Updating android SDK from **Android Studio -> SDK Took**

Also installed latest api's

Answer (score 0):

**open terminal & write**

- flutter clean
- flutter pub get

**solve this problem**

Answer (score 0):

This Error is because the flutter does not find the SDK path. You just need to set the SDK Path by following the command using the terminal.

flutter config --android-sdk SDK_PATH

For example

flutter config --android-sdk D:\Android\Sdk

Answer (score -1):

Some Cracks in apk in build got me this problem , i **deleted apks in build and re run** it after cashes clear . worked fine for me.

Answer (score -2):

it always happen to me because my system is overheating and always trips off while compiling my codes. I resolved it by running "flutter clean" and after that i run "flutter run" while connected to the internet.

Answer (score -3):

Deleting **AndroidManifest.xml** works for me.

Comment: This file should not be deleted