# "Could not identify launch activity: Default Activity not found" - Android Studio - no answers working

Tags: android, android-studio

Whenever trying to run the app, getting the error:

"Could not identify launch activity: Default Activity not found".

I have seen a few other threads on the same issue, but the below solutions have not worked for me:

1. Invalidating gradle cache and re-running
2. Manually overriding in the edit configuration tab to select the default activity (it then says "The activity 'MainActivity' is not declared in AndroidManifest.xml" even though it is!)
3. Re-syncing the gradle files
4. Literally shuffling around the order of the activities in my manifest
5. Using the long name for my activities, but doesn't make any difference

````
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.mywebname">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".ListenScreen"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>

 </application>

</manifest>
```

As you can see, I have clearly declared the activities (my app only has 2 so far), and I've put the intents around the ".MainActivity".
````

Comment: Did you try cleaning and rebuilding the project?

Comment: EDIT: I just cleaned and rebuilt via the Build tab and it is still coming with the same error.

Comment: do you still have an activity called `MainActivity`

Comment: @GregM under `Build` menu, you can find `Clean Project`. After cleaning `Rebuild Project` and then try to run your application.

Comment: @Lal just cleaned and rebuilt and still same error unfortunately.

Comment: @a_local_nobody yes I do, "MainActivity.Java"

Comment: did you move it to a different package/folder perhaps ?

Comment: It's still showing in my normal folder "java" -> "com.example.mywebname" -> "MainActivity"

Comment: You tried `File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart` ?

Comment: Yep - same error once it restarts unfortunately

Comment: click on main activity (the activity) and hit alt+enter, it should show a dialog of suggestions for what you can do, try adding it to the manifest through there

Comment: Can you please check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57173504/3168859)..

Comment: @a_local_nobody just tried that, still same error :o

Comment: it sounds like it's just android studio being weird

Comment: Yeah I think so - connected it up with GitHub last time before coming back to this project - could that be anything to do with it?

Comment: @Lal checked that answer and none of the solutions have worked for me! Literally no idea what to do

Comment: if you have it on github and you're willing to share, I can clone it and check it out for you only if you want @GregM

Comment: Can you just try after removing the second activity declaration from manifest..

Comment: @Lal - still throws the same error. I also tried removing both and adding them back into the manifest by going into the MainActivity class and hitting Alt + Enter to let Android Studio add it back into the manifest

Comment: @a_local_nobody- can I add you as a collaborator so the project can remain private? If so let me know your github username if you're willing to share

Answer (score 16):

This answer worked for me after trying so many other tweaks, just adding the package name solved my problems

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.example.name">
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/72300233/8720836

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31956474)

Comment: Worked in my case I had a newly initialised flutter project app.

Answer (score 1):

You can only have to add the package name inside the manifest tag you can find your package name inside app.gradle file and you are good to go