# stucked in flutter with many issues

Tags: flutter

I want to ensure codes works on emulator.

I just tried to run the preset flutter codes. I saw there is Turkish words on path, I changed that. But it didn't change in path.

[image: problem image]

Comment: Everything there is definitely English... Have you tried searching your error messages?

Comment: `Is your project missing [file]? Consider running "flutter create ."`...you tried this?

Comment: First please read: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors   Then post your codes here source code + error in text. Also error clearly  says `flutter create .` to use here

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No application found for TargetPlatform.android\_x86](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54636718/no-application-found-for-targetplatform-android-x86)

Comment: It's never a good idea to store something as volatile as programming code/resulting programs on a cloud backup. You change the code a lot, many temporary files are created, etc. All of these actions trigger a backup process that runs in the background which you can't really control and it breaks something.


I would suggest you move your project files to a local directory and not store it in OneDrive.

Comment: @jnnksdev I know it isn't a good storing style. But actually my OneDrive is closed. I don't use that. Projects are in my desktop, "Masaüstü" means desktop in Turkish. But I don't know why the path is going that way to reach desktop.

Thanks for your advice and where should I store my files in HDD or SSD ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just moved the location of project and it worked ! Still don't know how or why but it works anyway.

Thanks to everyone

(I will add the **answer tag** asap.)